# Fitting the largest possible ball in a cup

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out a relatively straightforward geometry problem which I simply cannot solve. In short, there is a cup, $18$ inches tall, $13.8$ inches wide at its widest, and $10.6$ inches wide at the base, symmetrically sloping (i.e. $1.6$ inches on both side).

My question now is, what is the largest ball that will fit in this cup, provided it sits flush? It is assumed that the cup has a thickness of zero. I have estimated the ball to have a diameter of approximately $6.3$... inches, but can this be calculated more precisely?

Thank you

[Cup and ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSaIC.png)

Comment: What defines, 'sits?' Does it have to be entirely int he cup, or just stay in it without falling out?

Comment: Essentially, it sits like this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/sd5vuWR.png)

Please note that this ball overlaps, and is too large

Comment: Does "sits flush" convey that it does not protrude above the rim of the cup, or perhaps that it rests on the base of the cup?

Comment: It does not protrude above the rim of the cup.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$A$ can be found from  relatons

$$ \tan B = 1.6/18, \,B+2 A = 90 ^{0}, R=6.9 $$

and

$$ r = R \sin A $$